# What's the sixth word?

Tags: word

There's an integer *n*>0 such that subtracting *n* (where A=1, …, and Z=26) from some (more than one) of the letters in word #1 yields word #2.

Replacing the first plosive in word #3 by a fricative and the first vowel by a syllabic approximant yields word #5.

Replacing thunder with war in word #5 yields word #4.

In America, replacing what sounds like a plural in word #3 with what sounds like a comparative yields word #7.

What's word #6?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Word #6 is

> **Friday**

Words 1 & 2:

> Subtracting 6 from the first two letters in **Sunday** gives **Monday**.
>  (**S** - 6 = **M**, **U** - 6 = **O**)

Words 3 & 5:

> **T** (plosive) -> **Th** (fricative)
>  **E** (vowel) -> **R** (sounds like **er** (syllabic approximant) (?))
>  = **Tuesday** -> **Thursday**

Words 5 & 4:

> **Thursday** is named after **Thor** (god of thunder)
>  **Wednesday** is named after **Woden** (god of war)

Words 3 & 7:

> Replace **Tues** (sounds like a plural of **Twos**) with **Satur** (sounds like **sadder** (comparative) (thanks OP!)) to give **Saturday**

Comment: rot13("Fnghe (fbhaqf yvxr n jbeq raqvat va re (pbzcnengvir))" -- fcrpvsvpnyyl, "fnqqre". Gurl fbhaq gur fnzr sbe zbfg Nzrevpnaf, juvpu vf jul V fcrpvsvrq "Va Nzrevpn".)